# Create unique dynamic cookie until delete cookie

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

How to create unique dynamic cookie until the cookie is deleted. I am using

```
 setcookie("name",uniqid(), 0, "/");
```

But its generates a new name for every page load but I want only one name until the cookie is deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first check if the user has a cookie set, and if it contains the information you're looking to save in it. If it isn't set, then you create a new name for it. If it's set, re-create it using the same name.
To test whether or not it's set, then you need to loop through the `$_COOOKIES` array, and check for a specific key. Which is a rather haevy-handed approach.

That is why this is, generally, not the best of ideas. As the name of the cookie should be static, but rather contain a randomly created key that points to the content in a DB. Makes checking for the cookie easy, and it helps you save the data out of the reach from the user (to prevent manipulation).

That said this sounds very much like a session, unless you want the cookie to persist even if the browser is closed. If this is not a concern, and the cookie should be deleted when the browser is closed, I recommend just using the sessions instead: Much simpler. :)

Comment: i want to create cookie dynamic and store it in db

Comment: @Nadh I'm afraid that didn't make any sense. A cookie is always stored in the browser, not the DB of the server.

Comment: Is it not possible to create dynamic cookie?

Comment: @Nadh As I said in my answer: It is possible to create a cookie with a dynamic name, _but_ it is not a good solution in most cases. Since you haven't explained what you are trying to solve with this "dynamic cookie", I cannot give you any further assistance on how to best solve your issue. That said, I did outline three different methods you could solve your issue, one of them should be a good solution to your problem. Remember: What you think might be the only (or best) way to solve a problem, isn't necessarily so. Especially since you're pretty new to programming.